# Is it possible to encrypt ubuntu 12.04 filesytem without erasing Data

Tags: 12.04, encryption, truecrypt

I'm using Acer notebook with windows7 and ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop installed in separate drive. I want to encrypt my ubuntu file system. I was trying with truecrypt. In windows 7 I'm not getting any drive where I installed ubuntu to encrypt using truecrypt. Also I'm using grub for OS selection. In ubuntu truecrypt is saying "TrueCrypt can encrypt system partitions only under Windows." I think truecrypt needs to format ubuntu drive that's why it is saying this. Is there any way to do encryption without erasing data? If it can't be done then what can I do for encryption of my ubuntu data. Encryption is mandatory for me. Please help me to get out of these problem as I'm trying for 3 day's and nothing comes fruitful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1987630

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, TrueCrypt currently supports the following operating systems:

> Windows 7  (32-bit and 64-bit)
>
> Windows Vista
>
> Windows Vista x64 (64-bit) Edition
>
> Windows XP
>
> Windows XP x64 (64-bit) Edition
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)
>
> Windows Server 2008
>
> Windows Server 2008 x64 (64-bit)
>
> Windows Server 2003
>
> Windows Server 2003 x64 (64-bit)
>
> Windows 2000 SP4
>
> Mac OS X 10.7 Lion  (64-bit and 32-bit)
>
> Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard  (32-bit)
>
> Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard
>
> Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger
>
> Linux (32-bit and 64-bit versions, kernel 2.6 or compatible)

But TrueCrypt can currently encrypt the following operating systems:

> Windows 7  (32-bit and 64-bit)
>
> Windows Vista (SP1 or later)
>
> Windows Vista x64 (64-bit) Edition (SP1 or later)
>
> Windows XP
>
> Windows XP x64 (64-bit) Edition
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)
>
> Windows Server 2008
>
> Windows Server 2008 x64 (64-bit)
>
> Windows Server 2003
>
> Windows Server 2003 x64 (64-bit)

So it can read a volume that was encrypted under Windows in Linux, but it cannot encrypt a volume that has a [Linux File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Linux_file_systems).

Your solution, as [Web-E](https://askubuntu.com/users/35775/web-e) suggested, is to follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostInstallationEncryption).

But beware, this will encrypt a single user; if you wish to encrypt several users, you need to repeat the how-to for each one. And follow carefully the instructions, or you will be unable to log in with encrypted folders if your wallpaper is in an encrypted area.